# Xcode 7.0 watchkit only finds previously deleted images?

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I'm trying to set the image of a button in WatchKit using setBackgroundImageNamed. I have an image named KOne. I have checked that the targets are correct for this image and that its location is correct, pretty much all of the possible troubleshooting from related questions to ensure it's being added to the extension/app. However, the WatchKit won't find this image or ANY new images that I'm adding to it. It will ONLY find images from a few builds ago. For instance, I can set the button to an image named K1 from a few builds ago, but I deleted this image from the project entirely! Whenever I try to set it to KOne it says "Unable to find image named "KOne" on Watch". Even weirder, all of the code works on WatchKit 1.0 in Xcode 6.3, and I have no trouble setting the KOne image.

In case you're wondering, I tried logging the cached images on the watch, but there were none. I also tried clearing the cache using this code:

```
    [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] removeAllCachedImages];
    NSLog(@"%@", [[WKInterfaceDevice currentDevice] cachedImages]);
```

I've shut down my computer, reset all contents and settings on the simulator (EDIT: As I comment below, I had only reset the iPhone simulator). I just don't know what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

WOWWWWW. Well it occurred to me as I was writing this question that I had reset the Content and Settings of the regular simulator BUT, being new to the whole watch thing, it hadn't occurred to me to Reset the Content and Settings of the WATCH SIMULATOR. After I did that, it started finding my new images! So ridiculous. So if Xcode/WatchKit won't find your new images and they're not cached, RESET THE CONTENT AND SETTINGS OF THE WATCH SIMULATOR, not the regular simulator! They're two different things! And no, quitting and restarting the watch simulator didn't work. You actually have to reset the contents and settings.